# How to call jQuery function after redirection(which is caused by submit)?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, jquery-validate

I have such problem: I'm using rails, devise gem and jQuery validation plugin. I have after registration path, but I need to call modal with congrats message. So when I call submit - it is calling, but within a second it is closed, because of redirection to other page.

I need to call modal AFTER redirection, how I can do this ?
Here is my js code :

**EDITED: How to make it works? Calling modal if notice=...**

```
      $(document).ready(function(){
      if($('.notice').val() == 'Welcome! You have signed up successfully.')
     $('#congrats').show();

     $('.sign_up').validate({


    rules: {

        "user[email]":{
            email: true,
            required: true
        },

        "user[first_name]":{
            required: true
        },

        "user[last_name]":{
            required: true
        },

        'user[password]': {
            required: true,
            minlength: 6
        },
        'user[password_confirmation]': {
            required: false,

        }
    },
    success: "valid"
});
$(".sub a").click(function() {
    $(this).siblings("div").show("fast");
});//code for showing hidden areas
```

HTML code of alert:

```
        <div class="alert alert-notice">Signed out successfully.</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On submitting/validating the form just open the dialog box like

`$('#congrats').show();
return false;`

and on close of the dialog box just do

`form.submit();`

Comment: I need to open it AFTER submit and AFTER redirection it should stay. or call  .show after  redirection.

Answer (score 1):

You should put `$('#congrats').show();` in the view rendered after redirection, and call it on certain conditions. For example, if a `flash[:notice]` is set, you can check its value in jQuery and choose to show `#congrats`.

**UPDATED**

```
$('document').ready(function() {
  if($('.alert').html().indexOf('Welcome! You have signed up successfully.') != -1) 
    $('#congrats').show();
});
```

I tried it, it works.

Comment: I will try it. good idea. but it's not working for me at this moment

Comment: The val() is for values in inputs. html() had to be used.

Comment: And one more thing - when it is opened like that - it doesn't behave like others - it close only when I click at the cross, but others are closing, when I click anywhere. What could cause this ?

Comment: I think this is another question, isn't it? ;-)

Comment: I will post new question, because, when I added this line, my other js, which should open hidden area - isn't working now (

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11117865/when-i-add-line-of-code-to-my-js-file-other-part-doesnt-work-now